# How to identify the dynamic content (from oracle database) and insert into database using radio button?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, oracle, jsp, servlets

My oracle database consists of 4 tables. First table contains QuestionId(Pk) and questions,
second table contains AnswerSuggestionID(Pk) and Suggestions, third table contains categoryId(Pk) and Category, fourth table contains displayid(pk), QuestionId(fk), AnserSuggetionId(fk) and categoryId.

my jsp page code :

```
<tr>
 <td class="regis" valign="top"><%=qId %></td><td class="regist" valign="top">       <%=questions %></td>
 <td class="regis" valign="middle"><input type="radio" id="rname" name="<%=qId %>" value="yes" class="rsubmit" onclick="<%=qId %>()" /><span>Yes</span>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;<input type="radio" name="<%=qId %>" value="no" checked="checked" onclick="<%=questions %>()"/><span>No</span></td>
  <td>**onclick radio button yes then i have to display suggestions here without refresh the page.**</td>
```

note:
some times one questions will have 2 or more suggestions.
some times category will be same for more than 2 questions.
some times for 2 questions answer will be the same.

Thanks with Regards,
Randeep

Answer (score 1):

Logically you should not have radio buttons if you can have more than one correct answer.

Secondly I would suggest to have a submit button. Only on the click of button should you submit the form and save the data into the database.

Comment: No no.. 
If you click on 'yes' button then only the suggestions will be displayed. Again if you clicked on 'no' button it will disappear.
And i am having a submit button for inserting all the values together.
And at last if you clicked on the submit button , then i have to  insert  only the contents which is 'yes'

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest that you use a link or button instead of your radio buttons to download dynamic content. Anyway, let's continue with your code for 'Yes' radio button:

```
<input type="radio" id="rname" name="<%=qId %>" value="yes" class="rsubmit" onclick="<%=qId %>()" /><span>Yes</span>
```

First thing first: you cannot have `<%=qId %>()` in the onclick attribute of your radio button. You should create a Javascript function, say `downloadContent()`, and pass on it's reference here.

```
var downloadContent = function(question_id) {
    // your code goes in here
};
```

Now you should refer it to `onclick` handler as follows:

```
<input type="radio" id="rname" name="<%=qId %>" value="yes" class="rsubmit" onclick="downloadContent(<%=qId %>)" /><span>Yes</span>
```

Now in `downloadContent()` you can make an AJAX call and download relevant data from your server in the form of XML or JSON. Next you would iterate this data and update your DOM. Working with AJAX and DOM can be tricky with ordinary Javascript, therefore I would highly suggest using a framework such as jQuery. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok. but if i am using the JavaScript, its not working properly. 

`<script type="text/javascript">
  var DisplayQuestId = function(<%=qno %>){
   document.getElementById('<%=sug1 %>').style.display="";
  }
  var DisplayQuest = function(<%=questions %>){
   document.getElementById('<%=sug1 %>').style.display="none";
  }
  </script>`

Comment: Couldn't get what you are trying to do with your Javascript. You never pass a parameter value in function definition as you are doing in 'var DisplayQuestId = function(<%=qno %>)'. You define function parameter instead such as 'var DisplayQuestId = function(qno)'.

Comment: Hi, questionId is dynamically coming from database, and for each questionId 'yes' and 'no' buttons also generated.
so if i click yes button for question number one then it should have to display the suggestion(answer), only for question one.
so how will i identify the question id in javascript?
And how will i keep the 'function(qno)' ?

Comment: Hi, 

how to get the id of the particular `<span>` ?
onclick radio button the function will work like `document.getElementById('xxx').style.display="none";`
what should i give instead of xxx to identify the suggestion(or answer) of the particular question.

note: The `<span>` is dynamically creating for each questions.